# Can I overload toString method for my enum types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating enums type as:

```
var myEnumType = {};
Object.defineProperty(myEnumType , "Prop1", { get: function () { return 0; } });
Object.defineProperty(myEnumType , "Prop2", { get: function () { return 1; } });
...
```

I tried to overload toString method as:

```
myEnumType.Prop1.toString = function () { return "Property 1"; }
myEnumType.Prop2.toString = function () { return "Property 1"; }
...
```

When I use myEnumType.Prop1.toString() it returns "0" and not "Property 1".
Is there way to overload toString method for singleton myEnumType variable (type)?

Comment: Just FYI, `myEnumType` is an Object and not ENum. And Yes you can do `Object.prototype.toString = function(){}` but this will be applicable to all object. If you wish to have special handling, create your own class

Comment: The problem is that you are defining a [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) method for `Prop1`, so whenever you access that property, it calls your getter (returning `0`), which you then call `toString()` on.